# Why can't Selenium find it using this XPath expression even though I copied it from the browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm having a hard time clicking a particular link. I tried using `find_element_by_css_selector` and `find_element_by_xpath`. Both give me the following error, even though I copied the XPath expression from the browser. I thought maybe I needed to wait for the page to load, so I added a 30 second timer, but it still couldn't find the element.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='ctl00_cphMain_RadDock1455_C_ctl00_gridTimesheets_ctl00__0']/td[2]/a"}

HTML:

[image]

Code:

```
time.sleep(30)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphMain_RadDock1455_C_ctl00_gridTimesheets_ctl00__0']/td[2]/a")
link.click()
```

Comment: Can you share the URL you are scrapping?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not.

Comment: The HTML content can easily be copied out (web developer tools?). Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72037516/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id that you are using with your XPath expression, `ctl00_cphMain_RadDock1455_C_ctl00_gridTimesheets_ctl00__0'`, could be dynamic in nature, which means at run time some value may change, and you may get `NoSuchElement exception`.

You can use `link_text` or `partial_link_text` in case *Data Analyst* is unique text wrapped inside the *anchor tag*.

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Data Analyst").click()
```

in general should work. However, if you are looking for a reliable solution, you should go for explicit waits:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Data Analyst"))).click()
```

You'd have to import below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In case you are looking for `xpath-based locator`, you can use

```
//tr[@class='rgRow']//td[2]/a[@title='Data Analyst' and text()='Data Analyst']
```

All in all, you've to make sure that it is unique in nature.

**Steps to check:**

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome → go to the *element* section → do a Ctrl + <kbd>F</kbd> →. Then paste the XPath expression and see if your desired *element* is getting **highlighted** with *1/1* matching node.

NoSuchElementException:

Please check in the [Web development tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools) (Google Chrome) if we have **unique** entry in the HTML [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) or not.

The XPath expression that you should check:

```
//tr[@class='rgRow']//td[2]/a[@title='Data Analyst' and text()='Data Analyst']
```

**Steps to check:**

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome → go to `element` section → do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> → then paste the XPath expression and see, if your desired *element* is getting **highlighted** with *1/1* matching node.

If this is unique, `//tr[@class='rgRow']//td[2]/a[@title='Data Analyst' and text()='Data Analyst']` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

   **Solution:** Switch to the iframe/frame/frameset first and then interact with this web element.
2. Check if it's in any *shadow-root*.

   **Solution:** Use `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector` to have returned a web element and then operates accordingly.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some *hardcoded delay* or *explicit wait* and try again.

   **Solution:** `time.sleep(5)` or

   `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='rgRow']//td[2]/a[@title='Data Analyst' and text()='Data Analyst']"))).send_keys("test")`
4. If you have redirected to a *new tab/ or new window* and you have not **switched** to that particular *new tab/new window*, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.

   **Solution:** switch to the relevant window/tab first.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first *switch to default content* and then interact with it.

   **Solution:** switch to the default content and then switch to the respective iframe.

Comment: The desired element does get highlighted, however I receive a timeout error. Even changing the time from 20 to 60 seconds produces a timeout error. I tried both By.LINK_TEXT and By.XPATH.

Comment: for this xpath `//tr[@class='rgRow']//td[2]/a[@title='Data Analyst' and text()='Data Analyst']` do you see 1 of 1 entry or 1 of n number entry in HTML-DOM ?

Comment: Very odd, it is one of one. Does it matter perhaps that it is a javascript link? Or maybe that its a table inside of a table? I wouldn't think so since the XPATH is being highlighted.

Comment: Check the update section above, should help you resolve the NoSuchElement exception.

Comment: Thanks for the write up my dude, its inside an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
time.sleep(30)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Data Analyst']")
link.click()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.